# Why we can not define a variable twice in switch?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Why this is illegal:

```
switch(x) {

case 1:
   int a = 1;
   break;
case 2:
   int a = 2;
   break;
}
```

It looks like it could have been legal. What are some deeper reasons for that to be illegal?

Comment: You seem to want to refer to `a` after the switch. But to which `a` ?

Comment: Variable scope is the name of the game. You can't have two variables with the same name on the same scope.

Comment: @dystroy No, suppose I never need a after the switch

Comment: Without using `break` code from case 2 would be executed as part of case `1` for `x=1`.

Comment: @Pshemo but there is a break

Comment: enclose each block with brace. case 1:{
   int a = 1;
   break;}

Comment: Yes, but why switch has to define a scope?

Comment: There can also be `break` in `while(true){int a=1; break; int a=2;}` and should compiler in that case let you redeclare `int a=2;`? `case` is just place (based on some condition) where code should start in scope provided by `switch block`.

Comment: Follow best practices. Switch is antipattern. You can use hashmap or polymorphism to solve problems without switch. If you want to use switch, you should have only one method call in each branch.

Comment: Switch is antipattern? Wow, never heard of that before. I think it's bullshit

Answer (score 43, accepted):

if the break statements are not used, Then we know that the following cases will be executed. So if you are permitted to declare in both cases that will cause a conflict. For example

```
switch(x) {

case 1:
   int a = 1;  // i have removed the break;
case 2:
   int a = 2; // now what will happen here :)
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 47):

Because the scope is delimited by `{` and `}` and you have the `a` variable twice.

You can avoid this compilation error by:

```
switch(x) {
    case 1: {
        int a = 1;
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
       int a = 2;
       break;
    }
}
```

---

Note that in your example the compiler fails to succeed, because if you remove the first `break` statement, а something that is called [fall-through](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) might happen:

> All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered.

In this case the statements that are going to be executed (because of the *fall-through*), are :

1. `int a = 1;`
2. `int a = 1;`
3. `break;`

And as you can see, the `a` variable is duplicated, which is why the compiling fails in your example.

Comment: It's useless : a isnt' available after the switch.

Comment: What is the reason for a switch to have exactly such scope?

Comment: @dystroy It's useless because it's a minimal example of syntax...

Comment: @Alex There's no reason for it, it's just an effect of C-style scoping.

Answer (score 8):

There's nothing related to a `switch` here. You simply can't declare the same variable twice in the same scope.

This is illegal :

```
int a = 1;
int a = 2;
```

Now, let's suppose you wanted, in fact, your case branchs to act as scopes. Then the problem would be that you wouldn't have been able to use the variable after the switch (outside of scope).

Answer (score 4):

The scope of the variables in each **case** clause corresponds to the whole **switch** statement.

However, if you want to use the same variable, you can define your own block inside each case statement by using the curly braces { and }.

Answer (score 2):

The switch statement is a code block. The switch statement evalutates it's expression, then executes all statements that follow the matching case label.

In this case it evaluates `x` and this is compared with each constant until a match is found.

But actually it is like saying:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int i = 1;
}
```

this will also not work, because `i` is already defined.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `a` inside the local scope of the switch. As such, you assign `a` a value but you do not pass that value anywhere so it seems redundant.

If you were to declare `a` outside the switch and then call it within the switch it should work.

```
int a;

switch(x) {
case 1:
   a = 1;
   break;
case 2:
   b = 2;
   break;
}
```

Alternatively, in each case of the switch, you could manipulate your new int and then do something with it like so:

```
switch(x) {
case 1:
   int a = 1;
//do something with your new int here that affects a parameter outside the switch
   break;
case 2:
   int b = 1;
//do something with your new int here that affects a parameter outside the switch
   break;
}
```

Plus, it appears that defining a variable multiple times in a switch is illegal due to conflictions, as the variable a is defined within local scope to mean one thing in the first case of the switch. As such, you cannot define it to mean something else in the second case.

Answer (score 0):

Go with these facts:
->You cannot declare the same local variable twice in single scope.
->`case` does not create its own scope.
->`switch`, yes creates its own scope.
->Proof: If you do not `break` a case, all the cases will be executed unless they satisfy the condition. (unlike else if).